# Conditionally setting background color to yellow with googlesheets api

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

[image]

I'm working with http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html a wrapper around the google sheets api v4. I am interested in setting conditional formatting using the google-sheets-api v4. I'm trying to use a custom formula to highlight a row based on the value of the "Q" column in the row. if the q column contains 'TRASH',  I want to colour the row yellow.

As I look through the pygheets library in https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/master/pygsheets/client.py and the sh_batch_update method

Further, I have https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting#add_a_conditional_formatting_rule_to_a_set_of_ranges Based on this I have:

```
import pygsheets

def cfr1(sheetId):

    # Apply to range: A1:R
    # Format cells if...: Custom formula is
    # (formula:) =$Q1="TRASH"

    return {
          "addConditionalFormatRule": {
            "rule": {
              "ranges": [
                {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "startColumnIndex": 'A',
                  "endColumnIndex": 'R',
                  "startRowIndex": 1,
                  "endRowIndex": 8
                }
              ],
              "booleanRule": {
                "condition": {
                  "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "userEnteredValue": '=$Q1="TRASH"'
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "format": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                          "yellow": 1.0
                          # "green": 0.0,
                          # "blue": 0.0
                        }


                }
              }
            },
            "index": 0
          }
        }
```

when I run:

```
    gc.sh_batch_update(ssheet.id,cfr1(ws.id))
```

I'm getting:

```
"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "yellow" at 'requests[0].add_conditional_format_rule.rule.boolean_rule.format.background_color': Cannot find field.">
```

This does work for primary colours green, red and blue. How do I format to a yellow background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have yellow as color , it should be in RGB format, see [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#color). So, for yellow you will need red=1, green=1, blue=0